# Australian resident libels UK resident

Tags: australia, defamation

Can a UK Resident sue an Australian Resident for Libel or Defamation, as in Australia, If the sender of emails had lived in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

### Sure

If the Australian defames the UK citizen to a third party the UK citizen can take legal action wherever the defamation took place.

However, be aware that defamation requires making untrue statements that damage the reputation to a third party. Calling someone a @#$& to their face is not defamation.

Comment: Thank You. An UK Executor of Probate/Will has been accused, amongst other thing, of stealing from the estate in an email from one of the beneficiaries who lives in Australia which is totally unfounded. All beneficiaries have been included.

Comment: If someone in Australia e-mails a defamatory statement about someone in the UK to someone else in the UK, where has the defamation taken place?  Does the answer change if the e-mail was sent to multiple people, at least one of whom was in Australia or was somewhere other than Australia and the UK?  I realize this could be a separate question but since this answer relies on "wherever the defamation took place" it ought to include at least a broad statement about how that would be determined.

Comment: @phoog That's probably a question in itself.

Comment: The statement was emailed to 6 UK citizens AND 2 Australians !!

Comment: @Mary as I mentioned in my comment, I recognize that it is a question in itself, but this answer is nonetheless incomplete without addressing it.

Comment: An Australian can be sued for anything happening anywhere in the world in Australia (at least in the Australian state where the Australian resides). Doing so might be wise even if other jurisdictions are available, since collection is likely to be easier in Australia.